# How to send data to another controller without GET method using link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails 5.2.2. I have `users`, `authors` and `books` tables. Every user can only see the records which saved by themselves.

Books table has `user_id` and `author_id` foreign keys. I need to save that data automatically.

In my `books_controller.rb` file I created a `set_defaults` method to add this data automatically like,

```
def set_defaults
  params[:book][:user_id] = current_user.id
end
```

There is no problem with the `user_id` but I don't know how to access the author id.

I added a link under the `authors#show` page and want to add book to author using that link.

So how can i get the author_id with the safe way?

```
<a href="<%= new_author_book_path(@author) %>" class="btn btn-block btn-info" style="color: white">Add a Book</a>
```

This redirects to `http://localhost:3000/authors/8/books/new`

I don't want to use the id from link and don't want to use get method. 
I only want to use the link (Add a book) to save a book.So how can i pass that author object to controller ?

Comment: What does your book html form look like? You could for instance have a select with available author and their id and send the data through the form?

Comment: I don't want to use any selection or similar. I want to add book records by using the link under the authors#show page and need to pass that author to the book controller.

Comment: controller name should be like `books_controller.rb` instead of `book_controller.rb`

Comment: @ray Thanks fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html form:

```
<%= form_for [@author, @book] do |f| %>
  # Your Book fields here
<% end %>
```

In your controller (without an authorization gem)

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @author = current_user.authors.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create 
    @author = current_user.authors.find(params[:id])
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    if @book.save
      # handle save 
    else
      # handle error
    end
  end 

  private 

  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title .....)  
  end
end
```

Comment: @author = Author.find(params[:id]).where(user_id:current_user.id) Which one is better ?

Comment: I edited my answer, didn't know about the relationship between users and authors

Comment: Thanks but i meant the create action. Isn't it better to use  "@author = current_user.authors.find(params[:id])" instead of creating a function(redirect_if_unauthorized) ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found a solution but i am not sure that it's a good practice. Any better solutions will be appreciated.

I created a global variable in author `show.html.erb` page :

```
$current_author = @author
```

And i used it in `books_controller.rb`

```
params[:book][:author_id] = $current_author.id
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. Any reason why you don't want to get the author id from the url using `form_for [@author, @book]`? (I'm assuming you're using a form helper, might help to have the html file as well)

Comment: How so? This is exactly what rails does when you use scaffold for instance

Comment: According to main post "Every user can only see the records which saved by themselves." i thought if user changes the url it would be a mess with other user's records.Am i wrong ?

Comment: What records are only seeable by themselves? Books? If so it does not change anything as I'm assuming anyone can add books to a specific author (which is the only param in the url here)

Comment: Both authors and books are user-specific.I mean 2 different users can have same author and can add different books but can't see the others books or authors.

Comment: You can enforce authorization using gems such as cancan or pundit, so users can't add books to authors they have not added. Or you can do this directly in your controller. I'll post an answer below